# IBM Websphere Commerce is running in RAD internal browser not in firefox

Tags: java, ibm-rad, websphere-commerce

I am new to IBM Websphere commerce.i am learning IBM WCS using info center using [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.developer.tutorial.doc/tutorial/ttd16.htm) .i successfully completed it's working in RAD internal browser not in external browser like firefox and ie. when i opened it in rad the log (console) is like
    [8/21/14 18:48:11:411 IST] 0000001c servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper doDestroy SRVE0253I: [WC] [/webapp/wcs/stores] [/Madisons/MyNewJSPTemplate.jsp]: Destroy successful.
    [8/21/14 18:48:11:432 IST] 0000001c servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [WC] [/webapp/wcs/stores] [/Madisons/MyNewJSPTemplate.jsp]: Initialization successful.

```
[8/21/14 18:48:11:438 IST] 0000001c CommerceSrvr  E LikeMindsFilter doFilter CMN3101E The system is unavailable due to "null".java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Hashtable.get(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.commerce.likeminds.filter.LikeMindsFilter.doFilter(LikeMindsFilter.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.commerce.campaigns.filter.CampaignsFilter.doFilter(CampaignsFilter.java:148)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:852)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:785)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:859)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
```

when i accessed it form external browser it the log is like

```
[8/22/14 8:57:24:847 IST] 00000026 CommerceSrvr  A StrutsViewExecUnit StrutsViewExecUnit CMN0203E: Command not found: "MyNewView".
[8/22/14 8:57:25:077 IST] 00000026 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper doDestroy SRVE0253I: [WC] [/webapp/wcs/stores] [/GenericApplicationError.jsp]: Destroy successful.
[8/22/14 8:57:25:093 IST] 00000026 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [WC] [/webapp/wcs/stores] [/GenericApplicationError.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[8/22/14 8:57:25:112 IST] 00000026 SystemOut     O ErrorDataBean:
Originating command:
Message Type: 0
Message Key: _ERR_CMD_CMD_NOT_FOUND
Message: CMN3101E The system is unavailable due to "MyNewView".


[8/22/14 8:57:25:113 IST] 00000026 CommerceSrvr  E LikeMindsFilter doFilter CMN3101E The system is unavailable due to "null".java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Hashtable.get(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.commerce.likeminds.filter.LikeMindsFilter.doFilter(LikeMindsFilter.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.commerce.campaigns.filter.CampaignsFilter.doFilter(CampaignsFilter.java:148)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:852)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:785)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:859)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
```

So any one please tell how to fix this?
Thanks in advnace

Comment: What is the whole URL you are using?  Does it include storeId/catalogId/langId?  Can you reach the out of the box madisons top category display page?

Comment: @MichaelRasmussen, This the url i am using http://localhost:81/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/MyNewControllerCmd?input1=wscadmin&input2=1000 and madisons store is working fine.i just followed the instructions in IBM infocenter "create a new task command" which included in Question itself. The problem is in rad internal browser it's working but not in firefox,ie,...

Comment: You are missing storeId/langId/catalogId, try swapping in MyNewControllerCmd for TopCategoriesDisplay in Madisons.

Comment: @MichaelRasmussen, i tried with swapping, it says generic error.Then i checked in the CMDREG table there is no command registered with the name TopCategoriesDisplay.And Some commands are registered with the name TopCategoriesDisplayCmd but their store id is 0.I am able to access Madisons store with this url http://localhost:81/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TopCategories_10051_10051.